# How to debug getStaticProps (and getStaticPaths) in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, debugging, next.js

I am trying to debug the `getStaticProps()` method of a React component included from my pages using `console.log()` like:

```
export default class Nav extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <nav></nav>;
    }

    async getStaticProps() {
        console.log('i like output, though');
    }
}
```

However, I am neither able to see any output on the console from which the app is being served, nor on the browser's console. I also tried restarting `yarn dev` and running `yarn build` to see if it would produce output then. Alas, no cigar.

So what is the correct way to produce and read debug output from  `getStaticProps()` and `getStaticPaths()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So after further research and testing I found out that `getStaticProps()` is only called on page components. So that was why I wasn't seeing any output. When I added the method to a component inside the `pages` directory I was able to see debug output produced with `console.log()` in the console running `yarn dev` on manual browser page refreshes (but not on automatic refreshes after modifying the page component) as well as during `yarn build`.

Answer (score 15):

You can easily debug server-side code of your next application.

1. To enable it you need to pass `NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect'` to your node processor. Best place to put it is in your package.json file where you run the app in dev mode => `"dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev"` .
2. Now open a new tab in your chrome browser, and visit `chrome://inspect`. This will open chrome dev tool inspect where you can see your nextJs server under Remote Targets, Just click `ìnspect`. By clicking that it will open a new inspect window.
3. Now simply put debugger inside your getStaticProps function and reload your client app, you will see the breakpoint in your server side code.

I hope this helps.
Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging#server-side-code

Comment: Environment variable can be set for several environments using "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev". Also see https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Comment: For me it did not work to drag and drop files to dev tools and set break points in that original files directly. Instead, I had to search for the file with Ctrl+P and set the break points in the "compiled files" whose url look like webpack-internal:///src/pages/...

Comment: @jeancallisti i think you wrote it in the wrong order it should be 

"dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev"

Answer (score 5):

Using the current next version (11.x) you can use console.log to print out any data in the getStaticProps() function.

You will see that output in the terminal where you run

```
   vercel dev
```

Answer (score 4):

getStaticProps runs on the server-side and not on the client-side.

`getStaticProps only runs on the server-side. It will never run on the client-side. It won’t even be included in the JS bundle for the browser.`

Ref: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/getstaticprops-details

Answer (score 3):

It turns out Next deliberately hides `console.log` output in `getStaticProps` functions (and presumably other server-side code).

However, there's a simple fix to disable that behavior!  In `next.config.js` add:

```
compiler: {
    removeConsole: false,
},
```

and the console output will appear again.

**NOTE:** It will appear in the terminal where you started the server (presumably where you ran `npm run dev`, since presumably you're debugging in a development environment).

It will not appear in the browser's console: since this is server-side output, it never makes it to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your console.log will work but in the console of your app Terminal, not in the console in the browser. There you can check your message.

Also, if you get data [Object] then just in that console, make JSON.stringify(yourValue).

if it's a bigger object than stringify you can write like JSON.stringify(yourValue, null, 2) and it will be displayed within JSON way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) only runs on server-side and never runs on the browser. So `console.log()` or `debugger` statement can't be visible in the browser. [When does getServerSideProps run](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#when-does-getserversideprops-run).

This is how you can see them:

- **console.log**

It will be visible in your terminal when you run your dev environment like `npm run dev`, `pnpm dev`, ... in order to start your server.

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')

  console.log(res)

  const repo = await res.json()

  console.log(repo)

  return { props: { repo } }
}
 
export default function Page({ repo }) {
  return repo.stargazers_count
}
```

- **debugger**

The `debugger` statement is a debug breakpoint, so you have to start your server in debug mode:

1. Add in your `package.json` a new script like `"debug": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev"`. Run it and get the correct port in your terminal. `(see the below picture as example)`

```js
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "debug": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev"
  },
  ...
```

Get the correct port in your terminal:
[image]

2. Just open a new Chrome tab and navigate to `chrome://inspect`. Click on the `Open dedicated DevTools for Node` link.

[image]

Now you can add a new connection:

[image]

After this operation you can just debug your `getServerSideProps` function like that:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')

  debugger

  // You also can use console.log()
  // console.log(res)

  const repo = await res.json()

  debugger

  return { props: { repo } }
}
 
export default function Page({ repo }) {
  return repo.stargazers_count
}
```

This is the `nextjs` documentation about [debugging](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/debugging)