# How to view Console.log() from client pages with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, next.js, console.log

I am trying to debug my client side renderings using Console.log() (If there is an easy way to use the debug tool, do tell) but I can only view server rendered conole.logs().

I am trying to see the flow of information for this handler:

```
const statusHandler = async () => {
   console.log("TRYING TO SEE STUFF HERE BUT UNABLE TO")
    try {call an API
    .....
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

This function statusHandler is called from a react component.

The page does have getServerSideProps() to initially render the page with database information.

I have tried using the browser developer tools but pages refresh and I can't track the flow of information.

Comment: You can enable the `Preserve Logs` option in the dev tools console's settings (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50977830/1870780). This will preserve logs even after a page reload. Alternatively, you can setup debugging in your editor, see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging.

Answer (score 6):

You can view you console.log() in CSR(Client Side Rendering) in  Browser press F12 or RightClick and click on inspect and check in console tab.

For SSR(Server Side Rendering) you can check in terminal

Comment: Is there anyway to see CSR in terminal? The pages refresh and I can't track the information.

Comment: The logs will only show in your terminal if you use console.log in your Node.js or Next.js server-side code.

Comment: Thank you. @ShubhamJasani you just saved me alot.

Answer (score 0):

To debug on the client side, you simply need to open the developer console in your browser. In Chrome and Safari, you can do this by `right-clicking` on the page and selecting the "Inspect" option.

Here, you will be able to see any `console.log` statements from code executed on the client side.

To debug on the server side using `debugger` statements, `breakpoints`, or `console.log`, you can refer to the answer in this Stack Overflow post: [How to debug getStaticProps (and getStaticPaths) in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63650473/how-to-debug-getstaticprops-and-getstaticpaths-in-next-js/76863089#76863089).

And this is the official documentation [Debugging with Chrome DevTools](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/debugging#debugging-with-chrome-devtools)